# Python 'all' function returns True with all false values in a dictionary, why?

Tags: python

```
_iterable = {'x':False,'y':False}
def all(_iterable):
    for element in _iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
print(all(_iterable))
```

**Output :**
True

Firstly i tried to change the values to True and False but the output stills the same even when i used `any()` instead of `all()`

Comment: You're iterating over the _keys_, not the values.

Comment: Try `for key, value in _iterable.items()`

Comment: use `if not element: False`

Comment: `all` is a buildin function but you redefined it and in the title speak about `Python 'all' function`, it is your `all()` function

Comment: @rioV8 `False` -> `return False`.

Comment: you can use print(all(_iterable.values)) ... and no need to define your own all(..) function, there is a build in one.  So print(all(_iterable.values())) works

Comment: you have programmed an incorrect `any()` variant not `all()` variant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to achieve what your are looking for. Here are 3 solutions:

0. To avoid the all(..) implementation problem, use the default built-in one. ANd/or change implemntation with a generator
1. you can use:

   ```py
   print(all(_iterable.values()))
   ```
2. or no need to define your own all(..) function, there is a build-in one which works perfectly. So it works even without the def all(..) part:

   ```py
   print(all(_iterable.values()))
   ```
3. you can change the function to iterate over tuples (key, values) instead:

   ```py
   _iterable = {'x':False,'y':False}

   def all(_iterable):
       for k, element in _iterable.items():
           if element:
               return True
       return False

   print(all(_iterable))
   ```

The easier:

```
 print(all(_iterable.values()))
```

result is as expected:

```
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, dictionaries are made by two components key and value. If you iterate the element you will get the key. There is a specific thing which you can get the value of the key element is dictionary_name[key]. In your code if you write _iterable[element] in that if part, you will get the value of your key.

```
    _iterable = {'x':False,'y':False}
    def all(_iterable):
        for element in _iterable:
            if _iterable[element]:
              return True
        return False
     print(all(_iterable))
```

True form of your code is here.

Comment: `return` breaks the `func`, loop will iterate only once, it doesn't matter what are the other elements  in `_iterable`. So you are just checking first `key-value` pair and nothing else.

Comment: OP has coded `any()`, don't use array index the iterable might not support it, use unpacking of element `a,b = element`